# Device Hub communication with printer queue

Tags: .net, printing, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm trying to print the Inventory Items as labels and we have this code to set a report I create that receives the InventoryCD and prints the label with a Barcode and the Inventory descr of said item... the code does send the report to the Device Hub by creating the print job to do so but the printer queue is not receiving the print job. also, it was working before but it stopped working when I cancel a previous print job of the printer queue received from the device hub Has anyone face a similar scenario?

thanks.

Comment: Are there any error displayed in DeviceHub window?

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA It appears that when you are adding one of the parameters to the report at least one of them has to be a public static readonly string with the following value for example $"{nameof(InventoryItem)}.{nameof(InventoryItem.InventoryID)}"; that solved it.